# integrating xml content into html page

Tags: html, xml

I want to add a CV page in my website. I wrote a cv in xml format and used xslt to describe it's representation (So simple so far). But the only difficulty is putting the xml text into the html page.
CV content should fit into a div witch i reference from menu buttons. So the output should be like `<div><table>...</table></div>`
How can i do it ? and what is the best way to do it (javascript or php ...)

cv.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cv.xsl"?>
<cv xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="cv.xsd">

<category name="Web">
    <skill name="HTML">5</skill>
    <skill name="CSS3">4</skill>
    <skill name="Javascript">2</skill>
</category>
</cv>
```

cv.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <xsl:for-each select="cv/category">
    <td><b><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></b></td>
    <xsl:for-each select="skill">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Solution found!   
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Finally i used PHP instead of Ajax:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->Load('cv.xml');
$category = $dom->getElementsByTagName("category");
foreach ($category as $cat) {
    echo "<div class='category'><span>".$cat->getAttribute("name")."</span>";
    $skills = $cat->getElementsByTagName("skill");
    foreach ($skills as $skill) {
        $name = $skill->getAttribute("name");
        $level = $skill->nodeValue;
        echo "<div class='skill stars".$level."'>".$name."</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```